# Difference between static and instance blocks

Tags: java, static, instance

Can anyone explain the output please? I don't get why after printing instance block code showing error.

```
class Test
{
    int x=5,y=6;

    static Test t=new Test();

    {
        System.out.println("instance block");
        System.out.println(t.x);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: First you will want to explain your question including the error message that you are seeing, where it occurs,... Please check out the [ask]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit more details about your question into the *body* of your question (not into the title). You wrote about an error, but didn't give any details of that error. Please provide more detail so we can help you. (I've removed the second copy of the code as it looked like it was exactly the same as the first copy. If there was meant to be a difference, please put it back in but make the difference clear.)

Comment: This exception due to static variables and initializers occurs before instant variables and initializers.

Answer (score 2):

The initialization of the `static` variable `t`:

```
static Test t = new Test();
```

creates an instance of `Test` class, which executes the instance initializer block:

```
{
    System.out.println("instance block");
    System.out.println(t.x);
}
```

The instance initializer block is trying to print `t.x`, but `t` is still `null` (since `t` can only be assigned a value after the instance of `Test` class is created). Hence a `NullPointerException` is thrown.